how to dynamically change locale with vue-i18n
The documentation here https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/started.html tells that the locale can be specified like this:
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'ja',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      message: {
        hello: 'hello world'
      }
    },
    ja: {
      message: {
        hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
      }
    }
  }
})

And then used like this:
const app = createApp(Vue)
app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#app')

I would like to be able to change the locale dynamically. I have a store that stores the current locale:
const appStore = useAppStore()
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: appStore.locale,
  // more code here...
}
app.use(i18n)

But this is not reactive. If the locale changes in the store, then the i18n object is not updated, and the locale is not really changed.
const appStore = useAppStore()
appStore.locale='en' // this has almost no effect, does not re-render the components

The i18n object itself does not have a method to change the locale, so even if I could subscribe to locale changes, I don't know how to reconfigure an already existing application to use a different locale. Otherwise, it would be fine to listen for changes, and programatically force a re-render when the locale changes.
But how?

pinia is not necessary, export i18n itself, import in file in which change local, call i18n.local = targetLang will do

Pinia is needed, because I want the locale to be reactive. E.g. if a component uses the current locale, and the locale changes, then I want those components to be re-rendered automatically.

@nagylzs by binding $i18n.locale on the "language selection" template model, it makes a double way binding itself, when   $i18n.locale  changes,  $t.messages[$i18n.locale] changes too

All right, in the final solution I did not bind locale manually, but used the el-config-provider component. I hopte it is not double binding.

After spending some time with this, I found a solution. Here are they key points.
i18n.ts

import en from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/en'
import de from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/de'
import es from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/es'
import fr from 'element-plus/es/locale/lang/fr'

export type SupportedLocale = "en"|"de"|"es"|"fr"
export const epLocales : { [localCode:string]: any } = {en, de, es, fr}


appstore.ts
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { epLocales, SupportedLocale  } from '~/i18n'

// this is just for the example, you can put the locale into any store...
export const useAppStore = defineStore('app', () => {
    const locale = ref<SupportedLocale>("en")

    const elLocale = computed(() => {
      return epLocales[locale.value]
    })

    return { locale, elLocale }
  })

main.ts

import './i18n'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import App from './App.vue'
import { useAppStore } from './stores/appstore'
// many more imports here...

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(i18n)
app.use(pinia)
// more uses here...
const appStore = useAppStore()
app.mount('#app')

Finally App.vue, with example content, the interesting part is how el-config-provider is used:

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useAppStore } from './stores/appstore'
const appStore = useAppStore()
</script>

<template>
  <el-config-provider namespace="el" :locale="appStore.elLocale">
    <RouterView /> <!--- or your main component here... -->
    </template>
  </el-config-provider>
</template>

</style>

The locale can be changed from anywhere, e.g.:
const appStore = useAppStore()
appStore.locale = "fr"

When the locale in the store is changed, then el-config is changed and any reactive component that uses the locale is re-rendered.
